# Azure functions get logon identify

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-functions

I'm quite new to Azure functions so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to get the user logon identify, previously I have been able to do this with `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`. Iv'e tried User.Identity in `HttpRequestMessage` but the name is always empty.

Has any successfully done this or is it not possible within functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your configuration. By default are functions with a http trigger authenticated by a key and not a user identity.

Answer (score 0):

> Has any successfully done this or is it not possible within functions?

For user-based authentication, go to your Function App Settings, click "NETWORKING > Authentication / Authorization" under the Platform features tab as follows:

[image]

You could leverage the build-in identity providers (`Azure Active Directory`, `Facebook`, `Google`, `Microsoft Account`, and `Twitter`) supported by App service, and follow [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) to configure your identity provider(s).

**run.csx:**

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req,TraceWriter log,ExecutionContext context)
{ 
   //return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Select(c => new { key = c.Type, value = c.Value }),"application/json");
   return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new { username=ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name },"application/json"); 
}
```

When I access `https://{my-funapp-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/{HttpTrigger-functionname}` via the browser, I need to login first, then I could retrieve the current logged user name:

[image]